# Dagger2 Injection compile error on ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I'm using Dagger2 latest Android Injection model (with `AndroidInjection` class) in my application. Until now, everything was working fine, including `ViewModelFactory` injection, but I only had parameterless constructors on my ViewModels.
While implementing new features, I've created a ViewModel extending `AndroidViewModel` (I need the context in that viewmodel). `AndroidViewModel` needs an `Application` as constructor parameter, so I've added it as injected parameter in the constructor of my ViewModel.
Since then, Dagger2 does not compile with following error :

> AppComponent.java:6: error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>   android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject
>   constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.

I understand this means my `Application` object is not available in the graph, but I'm adding it in my App class, thus I don't really know how to correct this.

Here are the classes implicated in my process. I'll mark any changes made for my last feature :

```
class MobileApp : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector() = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AppInjectorKt.injectApp(this)
    }
}
```

AppComponent.kt :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class))
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MobileApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: MobileApp): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    override fun inject(app: MobileApp)
}
```

AppModule.kt :

```
@Module(includes = arrayOf(ViewModelModule::class))
class AppModule
```

ActivityBuilder.kt :

```
@Module
internal abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(ResultModule::class))
    internal abstract fun contributeResultActivity(): ResultActivity

//This block is new
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(AltimeterActivityModule::class))
    internal abstract fun contributeAltimeterActivity(): AltimeterActivity

}
```

ViewModelModule.kt :

```
@Module
internal abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ResultViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindResultViewModel(resultViewModel: ResultViewModel): ViewModel

//This block is new
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(AltimeterActivityViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindAltimeterActivityViewModel(altimeterActivityViewModel: AltimeterActivityViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: JumpTrackerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

}
```

JumpTrackerViewModelFactory.kt :

```
@Singleton
class JumpTrackerViewModelFactory @Inject
constructor(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>)
    : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in creators) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass)
        try {
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

ResultActivity.kt :

```
class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Injectable {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory


private lateinit var viewModel: ResultViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    [...]

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[ResultViewModel::class.java]
[...]
```

ResultViewModel.kt :

```
class ResultViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
[...]
```

AltimeterActivity.kt (this class is new):

```
class AltimeterActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Injectable {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private lateinit var viewModel: AltimeterActivityViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[AltimeterActivityViewModel::class.java]
[...]
```

AltimeterActivityViewModel.kt (This class is new):

```
class AltimeterActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(app : Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    companion object {
        val TAG = "AltimeterViewModel"
    }

    var pressureAltitudeLiveData = PressureAltitudeLiveData(app)

}
```

Moreover, I've modified my code in order to try App injection, and it's working, so I know app is effectively injected correctly :

AppModule.kt :

```
@Module(includes = arrayOf(ViewModelModule::class))
class AppModule {

    @Singleton @Provides
    fun provideThing(app : Application) : String {
        return "dqwdwqd"
    }
}
```

AltimeterActivityViewModel.kt :

```
class AltimeterActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(/*app : Application*/) : /*Android*/ViewModel(/*app*/) {

    companion object {
        val TAG = "AltimeterViewModel"
    }

//    var pressureAltitudeLiveData = PressureAltitudeLiveData(app)

}
```

If anybody has any clue on what's happening, thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Here: `fun application(application: MobileApp): Builder` Your component builder does not bind `Application`, instead it binds `MobileApp`. You need to provide/bind `Application` as well if you want to use it.

Comment: Hi @DavidMedenjak
Thank you for your help. I can't believe it was as simple as that!
I've learned a lot from your post, especially about the Binds annotation. Great job!

Comment: Go for this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956997/7558125