# How to use dependency injection for injecting constructor in a ViewModel

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am trying to implement the example on https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide. This explains how tan android app should be structured.

When I use the same code, I get following error.

```
java.lang.Class<com.example.UserProfileViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
```

I could figure out that this error has something to do with

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserProfileViewModel.class);
```

---

When I write a default zero input constructor for ViewModel I get the following error.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, android.arch.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference
```

I can not figure out the reason for this error and how to solve it.

Comment: What else have you done in terms of setting up dagger in your project? The code samples provided in the page you liked are not enough to set up dagger properly

Comment: I am very new to dagger, it would be very helpful if you can provide some example link for using dagger.

I included dependencies in gradle file to set up daggeer-2.

Comment: The set up for MVVM with architecture components is pretty complex, I have a sample project here which uses ViewModel and Dagger so you can take a look. https://github.com/Levi-Moreira/MockAppMVVM

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide viewmodel with constructor as a dependency in your Fragment, there is a different method for it,

Lets suppose you have a viewmodel class as belows,

```
class SampleViewmModel(dataManager:DataManager):ViewModel(){
  //some logic
}
```

Then you will need to create a factory class to support above viewmodel like below,

```
class SampleFactory @Inject constructor(var dataManager:DataManager): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(SampleViewModel::class.java)) {
        return SampleViewModel(dataManager) as T
    }
    throw IllegalStateException()
}
```

}

Now in your module class, you can inject above classes as below, (Note-Datamanager class is injectible)

```
//Provide Factory
@Provides
fun provideFactory(dataManager:DataManager): SampleFactory {
    return SampleFactory(dataManager)
}

//Provide actual viewmodel
@Provides
fun provideViewModel(sampleFactory: SampleFactory): SampleViewModel {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, sampleFactory)[SampleViewModel::class]
}
```

No in your Fragment, you can inject your viewmodel just like any other dependency,

```
@Injetct
lateinit viewModel:SampleViewModel
```

Comment: modelClass.isAssignableFrom(SampleViewModel::class.java) (.java is missing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Koin](https://insert-koin.io)** as an alternative for Dagger.
Koin have full **support of Android Architecture ViewModel**. It's extremely easy to use. I prefer it for small and mid-sized project.

```
// declared ViewModel using the viewModel keyword
val myModule : Module = module {
    viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) } 
    ...
}

// Just get it
class MyActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    // lazy inject MyViewModel
    val myViewModel : MyViewModel by viewModel()
}
```

[insert-koin.io](https://insert-koin.io)